# Promise.all not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I am having trouble writing an asynchronous function using promises

```
function requestsPlot(plot, info) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var plotObject = fieldsObject[plot]
    var sqr = new Promise(function(resolve1, reject) {
      debugger;
      get(createSQRurl(plotObject.polygon))
        .then(function(result) {
          plotObject.quality = sqrHtmlParsing(result);
          resolve1();
        });
    });
    var soilType = new Promise(function(resolve2, reject) {
      get(createSoilTypeUrl(plotObject.polygon))
        .then(function(result) {
          plotObject.soilType = soilTypeHtmlParsing(result);
          resolve2();
        });
    });
    var distance = new Promise(function(resolve3, reject) {
      var start = turf.centerOfMass(plotObject.polygon).geometry.coordinates;
      var end = info.homeCoords;
      get('http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/' + start + ';' + end + '?overview=false')
        .then(function(result) {
          var parsed = JSON.parse(result);
          if (parsed.code == 'Ok') {
            plotObject.distance = parsed.routes[0].distance / 1000;
            resolve3()
          } else {
            plotObject.distance = '';
            resolve3()
          }
        });
    });

    Promise.all([sqr, soilType, distance]).then(function() {
      resolve('test');
    })
  })
}
```

The idea is to resolve the promise returned by the requestPlot function after all promises inside the function (variables sqr, soilType and distance) are resolved. However, the promise is resolved while all requests in the get function are still pending. Note that the 'get' function also returns a promise.
Thanks a lot for your help!

P.S. here's the get function

```
function get(url) {
  var requestPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('get', url);

    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status == 200) {
        resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };

    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };
    req.send();
  });
    return requestPromise
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nesting promises within promises is a [well-known anti-pattern](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/).

You don't need any of those promise constructors because you already have `get` which returns a promise and you can just use it directly.

Here's how you can re-write your code:

```
function requestsPlot(plot, info) {

  const sqr = get(createSQRurl(plotObject.polygon))
    .then(sqrHtmlParsing);

  const soilType = get(createSoilTypeUrl(plotObject.polygon))
    .then(soilTypeHtmlParsing);

  const start = turf.centerOfMass(plotObject.polygon).geometry.coordinates;
  const end = info.homeCoords;
  const distance = get('http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/' + start + ';' + end + '?overview=false')
    .then(JSON.parse);

  return Promise.all([sqr, soilType, distance])
    .then(([parsedSqr, parsedSoilType, parsedDistance]) => 
      Object.assign(plotObject, {
        quality: parsedSqr,
        soilType: parsedSoilType,
        distance: parsedDistance.code == 'Ok'
          ? parsed.routes[0].distance / 1000
          : ''
      }))
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it really helped me to avoid watching this code...

Comment: wow thanks a lot for the super fast answer, also for the link about the anti patterns!

Comment: @ChristophPahmeyer no problem mate, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

In modern javascript with async/await syntax , the promise.all syntax should look like this

```
await promise.all([asyncfuntion1(),asyncfunction2(),...])
```

Dont forget to call your asynchronous functions in the promise list -> asyncfunction1() not just asyncfuntion1